# Filtering private Posts

Tags: posts, filters, private

i got a page wich contains only private posts. Is there a possibility to use the wordpress built-in filters like archive or category?

Comment: When you say a page can you be more specific? Do you mean a literal post of type `page` in the pages section of WP Admin? Or do you mean a post archive? What do you mean by using the built in filters? It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: You can set the content type of the page to "private", which allows you restrict that content only to users with the capability of "can_read_private_posts" or something.

Comment: On the website there are only private posts. I want to filter it with the standard widgets, but they don't allow filtering private posts.